# python2 - taskcoach and Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, python, dependencies, aptitude

I'm trying to install taskcoach on Ubuntu 20.04. It requires python2 and some other python2 dependencies.

I've tried to following the advices I've found at this link:  https://answers.launchpad.net/taskcoach/+question/690591

but no success.

These are the steps I tried:

```
#install python 2
sudo apt install python2
#install pip (2)  https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-20.04/
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install python2
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
pip2 --version

#install dependencies 
sudo pip2 install twisted
sudo pip2 install notify
#Download taskcoach_1.4.6-1.deb 

#editing /var/lib/dpkg/status and deleting those two dependencies from the Taskcoach package
kate /var/lib/dpkg/status
#original line is: Depends: python (>= 2.6), python-wxgtk3.0 (>= 3.0.0.0), python-wxversion, python-twisted (>= 10.0), libxss1, ttf-dejavu, xdg-utils, python-igraph
new line I put is: Depends: python (>= 2.6), libxss1, ttf-dejavu, xdg-utils
sudo dpkg --force-all -i taskcoach_1.4.6-1.deb
```

I still get the following error:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i taskcoach_1.4.6-1.deb
    (Reading database ... 283484 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack taskcoach_1.4.6-1.deb ...
    Unpacking taskcoach (1.4.6-1) over (1.4.6-1) ...
    dpkg: taskcoach: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
    taskcoach depends on python-wxgtk3.0 (>= 3.0.0.0); however:
    Package python-wxgtk3.0 is not installed.
    taskcoach depends on python-wxversion; however:
    Package python-wxversion is not installed.
    taskcoach depends on python-twisted (>= 10.0); however:
    Package python-twisted is not installed.
    taskcoach depends on python-igraph; however:
    Package python-igraph is not installed.

    Setting up taskcoach (1.4.6-1) ...
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
    Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
```

Basically the  /var/lib/dpkg/status for some reason gets recreated with the old dependencies when I try to install that package..

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

It clearly states it depends on those packages, then why do you change the status file? The dependent packages should be added to fix this.

Comment: I just followed the instructions in the link above. It seems that those dependencies are not needed following those steps